Creating new column in pandas based on list of tuples
I have the following :
import pandas as pd
ls = [(1,2,10,20,5),
      (3,4,30,40,10),
      (5,6,50,60,20)]
df_ = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1.1, 3.5, 5.4, 4.1],
              'col2': [11, 35, 44, 41]})

I would like to create a new column in df_ which will be created according the below rules:
Checking at each tuple of the ls:

if col1 is between the 1st and 2nd element of the tuple
if col2 is between the 3rd and 4th element of the tuple
if both of the above 2 conditions are true, then it should return the 5th element of the tuple, otherwise it should return None

The resulting dataframe should look like this:
df_ = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1.1, 3.5, 5.4, 4.1],
                  'col2': [11, 35, 54, 41],
    'result': [5, 10, None, None]})

How could I achieve that ?

An efficient option would be to use janitor's conditional_join:
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor

out = df_.conditional_join(
         pd.DataFrame(ls)
           .rename(columns={4: 'result'})
           .astype({0: df_['col1'].dtype, 1: df_['col1'].dtype,
                    2: df_['col2'].dtype, 3: df_['col2'].dtype,}),
        ('col1', 0, '>='), ('col1', 1, '<='),
        ('col2', 2, '>='), ('col2', 3, '<='),
        right_columns=['result'], how='left'
      )

Or using a MultiIndex of IntervalIndex:
import numpy as np

a = np.array(ls).T

idx = (pd.MultiIndex
         .from_arrays([pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(a[0], a[1]),
                       pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(a[2], a[3])])
      )

df_['result'] = (pd.Series(a[4], index=idx)
                   .reindex(zip(df_['col1'], df_['col2']))
                   .values
                )

Output:
   col1  col2  result
0   1.1    11     5.0
1   3.5    35    10.0
2   5.4    44     NaN
3   4.1    41     NaN


Firstly, the length of the list and dataframe isn't equal and I believe that this was a mistake in entering the question.
Considering this the following snippet will work.
df_["result"] = [
    ls[i][4] if (
        (ls[i][0]<=row["col1"]<=ls[i][1]) and
        (ls[i][2]<=row["col2"]<=ls[i][3])
    ) else None
    for i,row in df_.iterrows()
]


No, the ls is fine, you have to consider each tuple independently. There is not a one-to-one match between the DataFrame rows and the items of the list.
